# Outlook Add-in Can't Find Message in Client

Tags: outlook-addin, microsoft-graph-api

On our desktop add-in for Outlook, once we receive a token for the Microsoft Graph API we make a call to retrieve the user's email message from the following endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Messages/[message_id]

This call to the Graph API is coming from our server, so it shouldn't matter that the add-in UI is running in the browser or in the Outlook client. However, we're seeing that - sometimes - when running from the Outlook client, that the request from our server for the Message gets a 404 response.

I have captured the url and token of both requests from the web browser add-in and the Outlook client add-in, and tested each manually. Both api URLs were the same, and both tokens that were generated (one from the OWA add-in and the other from the Outlook client add-in) worked successfully when I tried them manually with Postman.

Any ideas why the requests from the Outlook client add-ins fail while the web-based add-in requests are successful?

Answer (score 0):

stmcallister--I'd like to restate my understanding of your flow a bit. In your question, you mention that your calls to the Microsoft Graph are coming from your service. Am I right to assume that your add-in is presenting the OAuth flow for your service's Application Id, collecting a Token on its behalf, and then flowing the Token back to the service via an API call? Do you flow Id, Access, or Refresh Tokens to your service?

If this is the case, then as you say it certainly shouldn't matter where your add-in is hosted at runtime. However, it's possible that your Tokens (specifically their claims) are slightly different based on the original login context (Browser vs. Office).

In either case, a 404 is an unfortunate response if there's a Token issue. If you can provide more details about the problem requests, then we can look into it.

Thanks,
-TimMc

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Our add-in has the user initiate an OAuth flow with Microsoft Graph. Then, when the auth token is received, we use that token to make a call out to the Graph endpoint listed in the question above. In some Outlook clients this request to get the message receives a 404 response. While in the browser this flow consistently works. Happy to share other details. What else would you like to know about the requests?

Comment: Thanks--the auth Token that you receive, is that an Access Token, an Id Token, or a Refresh Token? I'm guessing that it's an Access Token, and that you're making a subsequent REST call to .../messages/... with it as a Bearer Token in the request header. The messageId is being provided by Outlook APIs to your add-in, and in both clients you've confirmed that the Id is being properly provided?